# Datatable split column value based on character in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-dataset

I want to split the column of  a datatable like below

```
Message
--------
PR-111: test message
PR-112 - test message new
PR-113 : test message new2
```

It should split into a datatable like below

```
PRNumber    Message
------  -----------
PR-111  test message
PR-112  test message new
PR-113  test message new2
```

Note: There may be space before after the : or -

I have tried below but not giving proper result

```
 var r = dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(g => new {
           
            PRNumber = g["Message"].ToString().Contains(":") == true ? g["Message"].ToString().Split(':')[0] : g["Message"].ToString().Split('-')[0],
            Message = g["Message"].ToString().Contains(":") == true ? g["Message"].ToString().Split(':')[0] : g["Message"].ToString().Split('-')[1]
        }).ToList();
```

Can someone help on this please?

Comment: The above solution is not working

Comment: `g["Message"].ToString().Split(':')[0]` on the second line should be `g["Message"].ToString().Split(':')[1]` having said that you can just do `Message = g["Message"].ToString().Split(new[]{':', '-'})[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to create a new `DataTable` with two columns, you should create it first:

```
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("PRNumber");
dt2.Columns.Add("Message");
```

Now a simple `foreach` is the best way to fill it, LINQ doesn't help you:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    string message = row.Field<string>("Message");
    // now use String.Split with two delimiter stings including the spaces
    string[] cols = message.Split(new[]{" : ", " - "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
    dt2.Rows.Add(cols.First().Trim(), cols.Last().Trim());
}
```

---

Since you have added now some edge cases like these:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("Message");
dt1.Rows.Add("PR-111: test message");
dt1.Rows.Add("PR-112 : test message");
dt1.Rows.Add("PR-113 - test message new");
dt1.Rows.Add("PR-114 : test message new2");
dt1.Rows.Add("PR - 115 : test message new3");
```

It doesn't make any sense to use `string.Split` anymore, you need a simple parser, for example:

```
(string Number, string Message) ParseMessage(string message)
{
    if(!message.StartsWith("PR", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {   
        return (null, message);
    }

    var prPart = message.TakeWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c));;
    var prNumberPart = message.Skip(prPart.Count()).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit);
    string prNumberString = string.Concat(prPart.Concat(prNumberPart));
    string prNumber = prNumberString.Replace(" ", "");
    string messagePart = message.Substring(prNumberString.Length).Trim(' ', '-', ':');
    
    return (prNumber, messagePart);
}
```

You can call the parse method in this way:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    (string Number, string Message) = ParseMessage(row.Field<string>("Message"));
    dt2.Rows.Add(Number, Message);
}
```

Comment: This is also not giving the correct result. There may be space before or after the : or -

Comment: It's giving the correct result with your sample data. If you have other cases you should include them in your question and you should also mention them explicitly. So at least edit your question and add those edge cases to your sample table and the desired result table

Comment: @sandeep.mishra: the third row that you have added now is the same pattern as the first, so there is no problem with my approach. It will be added as: `PR-113` and `test message new2`. Have a nice day.

Comment: the first row is not working with the solution you provided. rest two rows are working.Please check that there is no  space before  :  in first row but in 3 rd row there is space

Comment: Is it also possible that there is no space around the minus sign? Does the number always start with PR-?

Comment: Yes , the number always starts from PR-

Comment: Also PR-123 and PR - 123 also can be the case